# Copy data into different named multiple sheets

Tags: excel, vba

Dears,

I am a beginner and tried to prepare the macro that enables firstly delete rows based on condition, than create new sheets based on criteria from the first main sheet and add data from the first main sheet into multiple named sheets.

- deletes rows based on condition (RUNs OK)
- creates new sheets based on criteria from the first main sheet (RUNs OK)
- adds data from the first main sheet (constant range I4:I6)
  into multiple named sheets to A1:A3 in all of them (being created by this macro). Unfortunately I do not know how to do that :-(

Could you possibly help me, please?

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

   Dim lastrow As Long, x As Long
    lastrow = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    For x = lastrow To 1 Step -1
        If UCase(Cells(x, 3).Value) = "0" And _
        UCase(Cells(x, 6).Value) = "0" Then
        Rows(x).Delete
        End If
    Next

    lastcell = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Obratova predvaha").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

    For i = 2 To lastcell

    With ThisWorkbook

    newname = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Obratova predvaha").Cells(i, 1).Value

    .Sheets.Add after:=.Sheets(.Sheets.Count)

    ActiveSheet.Name = newname

    End With

    Next

    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Obratova predvaha").Activate
    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Obratova predvaha").Cells(1, 1).Select

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

not very sure about your description, but you may try this:

**edited** to add a sheet variable and prevent any (possible?) time lapse misbehavior between new sheet adding and writing to it by implicitly assuming it as ActiveSheet:

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Dim lastrow As Long, i As Long
    Dim newSheet As Worksheet

    With Worksheets("Obratova predvaha")
        lastrow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
        For i = lastrow To 1 Step -1
            If UCase(.Cells(i, 3).Value) = "0" And UCase(.Cells(i, 6).Value) = "0" Then .Rows(i).Delete
        Next

        lastrow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
        For i = 2 To lastrow
            Set newSheet = Sheets.Add(after:=Sheets(Sheets.Count)) ' add a new sheet and hold its reference in newSheet  variable
            newSheet.Range("A1:A3").Value = .Range("I4:I6").Value ' copy referenced sheet I4:I6 values into newly added sheet cells A1:A3
            newSheet.Name = .Cells(i, 1).Value ' change the name of newly added sheet
        Next
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanx for this. Unfortunately it does not run properly (macro fill in the data even into the "main sheet". I have just needed to copy the data from the main sheet (name "Obratova predvaha") into all other sheets besides "Obratova predvaha"

Comment: data are in the "main" sheet (i.e. "Obratova predvaha" sheet) _already_, otherwise how could you copy their value from there to other sheets?

Comment: sorry...the data I need to copy already exists in the main sheet

Comment: If you need to cancel them just add `.Range("I4:I6").ClearContents` right before `End With`. And if my answer solved your question then you may consider marking it as accepted, too. Thank you

Comment: Still doesn´t work properly...when I use Range("A1:A3").value = .Range("I4:I6").value, macro copy the data even into the main sheet "Obratova predvaha" as well which is unwanted, I just need to copy the data from the main sheet ("Obratova predvaha") into the others (2,3....xxx = but named differently, not just Sheet2,Sheet3 etc).

Comment: my code does exactly what you described as wanted behaviour. and as already commented "Obratova predvaha" sheet range "I4:I6" already has values. so what's the point?

Comment: You are right, your code works properly but the new sheets don´t involve the value from the main sheet Obratová predvaha (the data from I4:I6 from the Obratova predvaha are not copied into new created sheets), that´s the point.

Comment: look, `Range("A1:A3").Value = .Range("I4:I6").Value` statement inside a `With Worksheets("Obratova predvaha") ... End With` block, is copying the referenced sheet (i.e. "Obratova predvaha") cells I4:I6 values into currently active sheet (i.e. the newly created one if you kept the statement right after `Sheets.Add after:=Sheets(Sheets.Count) `) cells A1:A3. So: 1) are you keeping the very same code as mine? 2) if yes, what values are you expecting in new sheets and in what cells, and what values are you actually seeing there and what values are in "main" sheet before the code runs?

Comment: yes, I copied it into my new file. re2) in new sheets I expect the values from the main sheet I4:I6 in new sheets cells A1:A3. Before the code runs. After it runs I see the values in the main sheet I4:I6, that are copied in the same main sheet into A1:A3 and new sheets are totally blank without required copied cell I4:I6 from the main sheet

Comment: cannot reproduce your behaviour. are you working with multiple workbooks?

Comment: not with multiple workbooks but with multiple worksheets

Comment: post some screen shots of your main sheet (with other sheets tabs visible beneath) before the macro runs. then after the macro runs (always with other sheets tabs visible beneath) along with the screenshots of new sheets too

Comment: superb, thanx a lot for your advice!! Works properly.